# How can I set a separate Database for testing?

Tags: java, database, glassfish, integration-testing

Actually when running Selenium test case. I takes the live (Main Database) database which is configured in Glassfish. If we add records for testing purpose then it will replicate in the Main database. This is not good know. So is there any way to have separate DataBase for Selenium test case.

Comment: Your question isn't really about Selenium, it's about how to set up a separate database. What database server are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Glassfish:

- Define your JDBC Connection Pool resource to refer to different databases for your production server vs your development server.
- If you're not running two different servers, then your first step is to fix that, and **be running** different servers.  And different database servers.  Never point your development machine/server at production data, or even the production database server.

Comment: Ok I can create a new JDBC connection pool. But how can I connect that connection pool using Selenium WebDriver.

Comment: You stated "I takes the live (Main Database) database which is configured in Glassfish."  The point is that in your test environment, you configure your database to be your Test database, *not* the Main Database.

Comment: Ok Thanks. For Selenium-WebDriver test case, where I can configure the test environment? Please tell me the steps.

Comment: I'm afraid I can speak to Java EE issues only; no exposure to Selenium.  I can make assumptions based on it being a test framework - and can add nothing beyond what I've already stated.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to do a unit test that should run on deployment, then you must create a second connection in your unit test program.

You might want to use an in memory database for this, maybe HSQL which comes bundled with the java sdk so you don't need to install any drivers and also you won't need to cleanup anything after the tests are run.

How you create the second connection depends on what you are using, hopefully you will have a central class or method to get the database connections, something like this:

```
Connection c = MyConnectionClass.getConnection();
```

so you will have it easy modifying the getConnection method so you can point out to the HSQL direct connection for your tests, with something like this:

```
public Connection getConnection(){
    if(testing){
        Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:mem:mymemdb", "SA", "");
    }else{
        //get your connection from your pool or whatever you are doing right now
    }
}
```

or also you can be more correct and create a mock for this class. But I'm not sure if selenium supports this out of he box.

And of course, you will need to create your database schema into the in memory database before beginning the tests. If you use hibernate or JPA for example then that should be simple (be sure that you add a second persistence unit and use that in this case), if not then you should have the scripts for your database and run them with JDBC as you would run them in any database.

Also if you don't want to run the scripts every time the tests are run use hsql but in file mode (change the jdbc:hsqldb:mem for jdbc:hsqldb:file it will use a file to store the database).

here's some info about the hsql database if you want to know more: [link](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/running-chapt.html)

Also if you dont like hsql you can try [sqlite](http://www.ch-werner.de/javasqlite/) (only for file mode) which I think has more tools for accessing it